# Flutter setState() not updating the view after Invoking Flutter Code From Native Side

Tags: android, flutter

I am trying to implement invoking Flutter Code From Native Side using method channel and working as expected. But having issue with rendering the view after trying to set the `state`. Can any one help to fix the issue?

Actually the `SimSlotInfo` is calling from the below widget,

```
List<Step> getSteps() {
    return <Step>[
      Step(
        state: currentStep > 0 ? StepState.complete : StepState.indexed,
        isActive: currentStep >= 0,
        title: const Text("Send SMS"),
        content: Column(
          children:  [
            SimSlotInfo()
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ];
  }
```

**SimSlotInfo dart class**

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutterdemo/model/device_slot.dart';


class SimSlotInfo extends StatefulWidget {
  //callback function
  final void Function(String) callBackFunction;
  const SimSlotInfo(this.callBackFunction, {super.key});

  //const SimSlotInfo({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<SimSlotInfo> createState() => _SimSlotInfoState();
}

class _SimSlotInfoState extends State<SimSlotInfo> {
  final platformMethodChannel = const MethodChannel('common_lib_plugin');
  List<SimDetails> simDetailsObj = [];
  //execute the below code while page loading
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    platformMethodChannel.setMethodCallHandler(handleNativeMethodCall);
  }

  Future<void> handleNativeMethodCall(MethodCall call)  async {
    // do some processing
    switch(call.method) {
      case "deviceInfo":
        var simData = call.arguments;

        var arrayObjsText = '[{"slot":0,"simno":"89911017061","deviceid":"3518920","carrierName":"Vodafone"},{"slot":1,"simno":"89101706","deviceid":"3511643","carrierName":"JIO"}]';
        List simObjsJson = jsonDecode(arrayObjsText) as List;
        simDetailsObj = simObjsJson.map((tagJson) => SimDetails.fromJson(tagJson)).toList();
        setState(()  {
          simDetailsObj = simDetailsObj;
        });

    }
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
        children:
        simDetailsObj.map((data) => RadioListTile(
          dense: true,
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          title: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Text(
                "${data.carrierName}",
                style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          groupValue: _selectedSim,
          value: data.simno,
          onChanged: (val) {
        
          },
        )).toList()

    );
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you are trying to assign List to List so your code is getting brake there. to solve that loop the object with SimDetails object. and that will do the trick

---

ParentWidget

```
class _ParentWidgetState extends State<ParentWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChildWidget(  // <---- child widget
      callSetState: (list) { // <--- callback Function 
        print(list);
        setState(() {
          // <---  
        });
      },
    );
  }
}
```

---

In Child widget

```
class ChildWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const ChildWidget({Key? key, required this.callSetState}) : super(key: key);

  final Function(List<SimDetails>) callSetState; // <-- declare callback function here 

  @override
  State<ChildWidget> createState() => _ChildWidgetState();
}
```

and replace your setState with `widget.callSetState`

```
  Future<void> handleNativeMethodCall(MethodCall methodCall) async {
switch (call.method) {
  case 'deviceInfo':
    var simData = call.arguments;
    var arrayObjsText =
        '[{"slot":0,"simno":"89911017061","deviceid":"3518920","carrierName":"Vodafone"},{"slot":1,"simno":"89101706","deviceid":"3511643","carrierName":"JIO"}]';
    for (var data in jsonDecode(arrayObjsText)) {
      simDetailsObj.add(
        SimDetails(
          slot: data['slot'],
          simno: data['simno'],
          deviceid: data['deviceid'],
          carrierName: data['carrierName'],
        ),
      );
    }
    /// setState(() {});
    widget.callSetState(simDetailsObj);
   
  break;
  default:
}}
```

Comment: I have added what you have suggested but getting same issue. i.e not updating the UI.

Comment: @Harsiman, Actually the `SimSlotInfo` widget is calling from another class where we have implemented the stepper. I have edited my post,

Comment: in that case, you can make a callback function and pass the data to parent and in the parent call the setState I have Updated the code please look at it